# bind value of text box to onclick paramater

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

```
  <input type="text" name="BoqTextBox" />
    <input type="AddValueButton" value="+" onclick="Add(BoqTextBox)" />
    <input type="MinusValueButton" value="-" onclick="Minus(BoqTextBox)"/>                           
    </div>

    <script>
        function Add(data) {
            var i = 1;
        }   
    </script>
```

User enters data into 'BoqTextBox' and clicks + button.
All Data in the text box is passed to the 'data' paramter in function Add(data)

How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to read the value of a textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should add an ID attibute to input[name=BoqTextBox] element because search an alement by name is more dificult. (see http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-get-element-by-name-in-html-getelementsbyname/)

```
<input type="text" name="BoqTextBox" id="BoqTextBox" />
```

Then change the onclick ovent to looks like this:

```
<input type="AddValueButton" value="+" onclick="Add(document.getElementById('BoqTextBox').value)" />
<input type="MinusValueButton" value="-" onclick="Minus(document.getElementById('BoqTextBox').value)"/>
```

I hope this works.